# Do I need to mount?

Tags: linux, command-line, mount

I do not have access to

```
/media/Acer/i/XAMPP/xampp/htdocs
```

until after I open a file from this location in gedit.

After this point I can navigate to it from the command line.

Comment: How do you get there in gedit? Open > Browse?

Comment: Before you go in to gedit (when you can't get there in the command line) type `mount` and see if /media/Acer is mounted.

Comment: Rudie - > I used "gedit & from the command line"

Comment: Matt -> No it is not mounted.  After I open it from gedit and return to the command line - it is mounted - verified by running another mount.  It appears that gedit performs the mount.  How can I have it auto mount every time I boot into Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably a NTFS or fat partition from windows from the name and from the path IS mounted. I suspect it needs permissions to open it - i THINK chowning the partition may help.

Comment: Gedit can mount the device.  Do gedit and the command line work off a different set of permissions, even though I am logged in as "chris" and do not use sudo to open gedit?

Comment: in theory, no, but apparently *something* with gedit is giving you permission to use it.

Comment: Basically, I just need to edit my etc/stab file. Found this solution on ubuntuforums.com (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=900175). Not sure why it does not come this way installed.